# how to run pip for python 3 and python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have two versions of python installed on my machine (Ubuntu 14.xx LTE) as well as two versions of `pip` (one for python 2 and one for python 3). When I run `pip --version` on the command line I get the following output: `pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. I looked into this directory and it has many other things in it. However I couldn't find `pip.py` in it. How do I run `pip` for python 3? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: pip for python 3 is called `pip3`

Comment: First of all it may have alias like ```pip3```. But you also may provide full path to it like ```/usr/lib/python3.4/bin/pip```

Comment: a comment for Debian users: your `/usr/bin/pip2` script might have `#!/usr/bin/python` <- with just "python" and no specific version. Then it will launch the default Python, which is 3 nowadays. So, edit it to `#!/usr/bin/python2.7` or whatever Python 2 you have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use another version of pip for python on ubuntu, you can use the python major version after pip. For Example:

```
pip --version
```

will return the default version of pip

```
pip2 --version
```

will use the Python 2 version of pip, and

```
pip3 --version
```

will use Python 3.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Also, you can access pip as a module for different OSes easily for different Python installs. "/path/to/python/executable -m pip --version" works great for Windows versions with multiple Python installs, or if the Python variable is added to the path, then "python2 -m pip" and "python3 -m pip".

Answer (score 0):

rename your python.exe for python 3 to python3. Don't forget to put it inside your PATH environment. Just use python for python 2, python3 for python 3.

Their pip are separated, pip for python 2. pip3 for python 3.