# start python, show the following logs ,however the flask was installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

call command on ubuntu17.04

> python3 /home/main.py

and  show the log as the following:

```
tail: nohup.out: file truncated
nohup: ignoring input
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from API import  Parse1
 File "/home/API/Parse1.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

the log which the flask is installed

```
  sudo pip install flask
  DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/home/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/home/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (0.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10->flask) (1.1.1)
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to run `python3` and installed flask using `pip` which is for python2. Try running `pip3 install flask`

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467535/how-to-run-pip-for-python-3-and-python-2 to find out how to use python 2 and 3 in the same machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run pip for python 3 and python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467535/how-to-run-pip-for-python-3-and-python-2)